# Angularjs - {{selected|json}}

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Why, if I put the input type before the `{{selected|json}}`, this doesn't work anymore?
I would like to keep my form tidy, but I can't make it work as I would.
(Unfortunately, seeing I'm new to code, I used a copy-paste&arrange pattern for this).

I have the autocomplete on the input type, that goes on a php array and returns the chosen value.
But, if the input type is before {{selected|json}}, it doesn't show the array.

```
 <button  type="button" ng-click="tasto =!tasto" class="btn btn-primary admin-tooltip"
         data-original-title="Seleziona un contatto">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
      </button>

<input type="text" ng-show="tasto" ng-model="selected" ng-click="connessione()" 
 typeahead="contatti for contatti in contatti | filter:$viewValue "/>
     <div class="dati">
     <div class="anagrafica">
<label class="label_sx">Cliente</label>
<pre>{{selected|json}} </pre>
```

Comment: Show the code that *doesn't* work (the version where the input is before the JSON block), and explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I hope I edited in the right way. Thank you!

Comment: <button  type="button" ng-click="tasto =!tasto" class="btn btn-primary admin-tooltip"
         data-original-title="Seleziona un contatto">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
        </button>
          <div>
          <div class="anagrafica">
        <label>Cliente
    <input type="text" ng-show="tasto" ng-model="selected" ng-click="connessione()"typeahead="contatti for contatti in contatti | filter:$viewValue "/></label>
    <pre>{{selected|json}}</pre>  
    </div>

Maybe is not the best solution, but coded like this, works.